# ElasticSearch Painless Script Not Working

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to use the following Painless script query in one of my applications, but it does not seem to be working. Any problem with the syntax? I noticed that the part that does not really work is this `Math.max(doc["level"].value, 1) - 1`. Please, note that "id" field is a keyword and "level" is a byte.

```
{script: {script: {
        inline: 'doc["id"].value == params.parentDocIds[Math.max(doc["level"].value, 1) - 1]',
        params: {parentDocIds: parentDocIds}
}}}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm struggling too. One thing when using inline is the use of ctx, so not sure it should be ctx.doc["id"]...

Comment: Painless seems to be type sensitive so I casted the returned value from Math.max like this: (int)Math.max(doc["level"].value

Comment: Can you specify the mapping of your index, and the purpose of this query?

Answer (score 0):

The following query will work. 
Change the index name to match your index and try it in Kibana.

```
GET todo-index-name-here/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "inline": "def idx = (int)Math.max(doc['level'].value, 1) - 1; return (doc['id'].value == params.parentDocIds[idx])",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
          "parentDocIds": [
            "x",
            "y",
            "z"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```